# Who is responsible for clearing up memory from image lists?

Tags: winapi, mfc, memory-management, imagelist

If I have a CImageList object (a simple wrapper around a HIMAGELIST), and I call:

```
m_pImageList->Replace(...);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k10cwcdb.aspx

Who is responsible for clearing up the memory? Does the image list create a copy of any bitmap I pass in (i.e. can I create a CBitmap object on the stack then pass the address of this to the function)? Or must I create it on the heap and remember to manually free all the memory when the image list is destroyed?

MSDN isn't very clear on the subject of who's responsible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, `CImageList` is a simple wrapper around an `HIMAGELIST`. `CImageList::Replace` just calls [`ImageList_Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775213.aspx), whose documentation states:

> The `ImageList_Replace` function copies the bitmap to an internal data structure. Be sure to use the `DeleteObject` function to delete `hbmImage` and `hbmMask` after the function returns.

This means you can create a `CBitmap` object on the stack, call `CImageList::Replace`, and the image list will take a copy of the bitmap from the `CBitmap` object. Then, when the `CBitmap` object goes out of scope, its destructor (or rather, the `CGdiObject` base class destructor) will call `DeleteObject` to delete the bitmap. Because the image list copies any bitmaps added to it, it should delete the bitmap that was replaced for you.

When the `CImageList` destructor executes, this calls `ImageList_Destroy` to delete the underlying `HIMAGELIST`, which should delete all the bitmaps owned by the image list.